# Friends Invitation Plugin - Hosted or PHP

Tags: php

I'm wondering if there's a good "hosted" solution for managing friend invites (ala LinkedIn) I know of AddThis, but unless I'm mistaken that looks geared towards sharing specific articles/content.

I'm looking for something that could be integrated neatly into the sign up process, with minimal added coding effort.  Just need simple grab contacts from Gmail, FB, Hotmail, etc.

Perhaps the best way to go is a PHP plugin.  Can anyone recommend the best one out there? Free would be best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://openinviter.com/

Answer (score 1):

There are [solutions](http://www.getmycontacts.com/) for sale, or you could write something.

```
require_once("libgmailer.php");

$my_timezone = 0;
$gmailer = new GMailer();
if ($gmailer->created) {
 $gmailer->setLoginInfo($gmail_username, $gmail_pwd, $my_timezone);
 //$gmailer->setProxy("proxy.company.com");
 if ($gmailer->connect()) {
  $gmailer->fetchBox(GM_CONTACT, "all", "");
  $snapshot = $gmailer->getSnapshot(GM_CONTACT);
  var_dump($snapshot->contacts);
  var_dump($snapshot->contacts_total);
 } else {
  die("Fail to connect because: ".$gmailer->lastActionStatus());
 }
} else {
 die("Failed to create GMailer because: ".$gmailer->lastActionStatus());
}
```